# c# uwp GridView ItemsWrapGrid bottom margin

Tags: c#, xaml, templates, gridview, uwp

In UWP I am creating horizontal GridView.

For ItemsPanelTemplate I am using ItemsWrapGrid as following:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                       MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"
                       ItemWidth="200"
                       ItemHeight="100"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

The problem is that I have some bottom margin that is the same height as the scrollbar. When scrollbar is hidden there is this empty space, and the items are cutted.

I have tried to change margins, paddings...but no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have this problem, I have just added:

```
Margin="0,0,0,-10"
```

inside ItemsWrapGrid.

And it fixed it.

Comment: It is possibly one of uwp's weird behaviours. You could try overriding scrollbar events, to have different settings when scrollbar is visible/not visible. Also you might want to mark this as answer if it really solved your problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer. I just can't mark it still.